# How to pan canvas horizontally towards negative x axis

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to implement sine wave demo with canvas.   I am able to draw sine wave with animation. But my problem is I want to move canvas towards left as Sine wave animation goes beyond viewport of canvas.  Here is my code.

```
<canvas id='a' width="320" height="480"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
var rot=0;
var c= document.getElementById('a');

function a(){
setInterval(function(){
   ctx=c.getContext('2d');
   ctx.fillStyle="red";
   rad=rot*Math.PI/180;
   var x=100+100*Math.cos(rad);
   var y=100+100*Math.sin(rad);
   ctx.fillRect(rot,y,1,1);
   rot++;
 },10);
}
a();
```

Comment: Maybe [Make and animate wave in canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787775/make-and-animate-wave-in-canvas/19803396#19803396) could help.

Comment: Thanks Anto, but MarkE gave me the exactly what I needed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/K6SL3/

Here’s an efficient way to draw a sine wave based on the X-coordinate:

```
ctx.fillRect(x,Math.sin(x/10)*30+50,1,1);
```

Until the wave reaches the end of canvas, just draw the wave normally

When the wave reaches the end of the canvas, you can redraw the whole wave, but shifted 1 pixel to the left.

```
// start panning when x reaches panAtX

var n1=x-panAtX;

// set up a temporary xx that draws the wave from -1 to the panAtX position

var xx=-1;

// clear the canvas

ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

// redraw the wave, but shifted 1 pixel to the left

for(n=n1;n<x;n++){
    ctx.fillRect(xx++,Math.sin(n/10)*30+50,1,1);
}
```

So putting it all together, your animation might look like this:

```
var x=0;
var panAtX=250;
var continueAnimation=true;
animate();


function animate(){

    if(continueAnimation){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    if(x++<panAtX){
        ctx.fillRect(x,Math.sin(x/10)*30+50,1,1);
    }else{
        var n1=x-panAtX;
        var xx=-1;

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        for(n=n1;n<x;n++){
            ctx.fillRect(xx++,Math.sin(n/10)*30+50,1,1);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, if you have other assets drawn on the canvas, you would have to also redraw them (redrawn with or without panning bases on your design needs).

Comment: Bingo!!! That's what I wanted. Thanks alot dude. I would buy you a beer if you were nearby...;)))

Comment: it would be great if u can tell me where can I get trigonometry based tutorials for canvas..

Comment: Good news...all the trigonometry functions are already built into javascripts "Math" method.  That means there is no "special" trig that applies to html canvas.  So any trig tutorials you find (eg youTube) will apply directly to html canvas.  Cheers!